# Zend_Framework - Class naming

Tags: php, zend-framework, naming-conventions

I wanted to use code like this in my Zend Framework project:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $user = new User();
    $user->name = "Guest";
    $user->save();
}
```

The main thing that is important for me is that the class is called just `User` and not `App_Model_User` but how could I manage that?
I thought I could add the path to the file `User.php` in the model-folder to the include_path:

```
<?php
class User {
    /* Some code */
}
```

But how could I config the autoloader to load that file/class?
Currently I'm using the autoloader with the appnamespace ("App") to load classes called `App_Model_User` which works but the class naming is not the right I think. It should be cleaner and clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `set_include_path` as follows:

```
$root = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));

set_include_path(
    $root . '/application' . PATH_SEPARATOR
    . $root . '/library' . PATH_SEPARATOR 
    . $root . '/application/models' . PATH_SEPARATOR
    . $root . get_include_path()
);
```

Then the autoloader picks up any models (with any name) which I put in /application/models. The above is in my only public facing script (index.php). This is how I set up the autoloader:

```
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
```

The second line will ensure that your models do not have to be explicitly included. See:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html

Comment: I tried the same but then I have to write `require 'User.php` that it works, but how could I config the Zend Framework autoloader to do that automaticly? PS: Since PHP 5.3 the `dirname(__FILE__)` could be replaced with `__DIR__`

Comment: Just discovered this solution and then I saw your edit, but thanks anyway ;)! Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

What is your version of PHP? You can use namespaces.

Comment: DEV system: > 5.3 but my server has 5.2.x :(